# When finding Laurent series when to use partial fractions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

When finding the Laurent series of $$f(z):=\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$$ valid in the region $1<|z-2|<2$ for example do we just use partial fractions to break $f(z)$ up and the just find the Laurent series for each part then add the series' together as per the partial fractions? This seems to make sense to me but I have seen some examples when partial fractions aren't needed so I just wanted to clarify, I guess when partial fractions aren't needed is when the region you want it to be valid on is nice enough; and by that I mean you don't really need to do any manipulations to exploit the geometric series.

Any clarification?

Comment: What kinds of examples have you seen that don't use partial fractions?

Comment: $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$ on $0<|z-1|<1$ for example.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the expansion (not via partial fractions) of that function? In some cases, given a rational function with a quadratic expression in the denominator, you would be able to complete the square and exploit (if you know it) the expansion of $\dfrac{1}{(z-a)^2+b}$ about $z=a$, though that doesn't seem to be viable here since you would find $a=\dfrac{3}{2}$.